# Which Function can make a Graph like this?

Tags: python, graph, scipy

I'm new to Python and I want to know what this kind of graph is called.

I particularly want to know how to generate those white lines. Those white lines should go up to infinite (the maximum of the Y-axis). The white lines represent a roadblock, as it were.

Anyway, I don't know the name for these white lines, or for the graph in general!

I have scipy suite of software.

[image: This Graph]

Comment: I edited your title to remove the stuff that should have been a tag

Comment: Which functions did you already tried?

Comment: Where did you get the graph image? What kind of data is it representing?

Comment: @rene i have successfully made a graph, but it does not have the white lines going upward. 

I used http://pastie.org/8358514

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Simply add another x and y axis which used the '--' line type. And my function was like this in the end:

```
x1.append(stepid)
y1.append(danger)
x2.append(stepid)
y2.append(dlimit)
x3.append(stepid)
y3.append(dlimit)
```